# How to update an existing node in xml file using php

Tags: php, xml

i would like to update an existing node, instead of creating/adding a new node with new values i would want it to replace the existing nodes, is there a way to do this and also limit the number of nodes in xml using php?

```
    <result>
     <team>
    <name>arsenal</name>
    <games>4</games>
    <points>12</points>
    </team>
    <team>
    <name>chelsea</name>
    <games>4</games>
     <points>6</points>
    </team>
    </result>
```

i would like the new values to check if the name is whether arsenal or chelsea or whatever and then just update the values, so the scores will update and the node name will stay the same.....score and points will be updated basically.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [PHP's DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to read and write the XML data. Good luck!

Comment: thanks buddy it helped me a lot, if anyone needs help with this, then look up http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php